# Connect Azure CA to SQL Server with user assigned managed identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep, azure-container-apps

I have setup a resource group on Azure in which I have a SQL Server with one DB.

I'm trying to connect a container app I have in this same resource group to the this DB by using a UAI I have setup for this container by using this connection string:

```
env: [
    { name: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID', value: identity.properties.clientId }
    { name: 'AZURE_TENANT_ID', value: tenant().tenantId }
    { name: 'ConnectionString', value: Server=${databaseHost},1433;Database=${databaseName};Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User ID=${identity.properties.principalId}' } 
]
```

All of this is done via bicep files as you can see in this snippet.

When my deployment is done, everything deploys fine and I can see that the identity of my container app is set properly. This UAI is also member of a DbAdmin security group I have created and assigned as owner of my SQL Server.

Here is the setup for my SQL Server and DB:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: serverName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: sqlAdminGroupName
      sid: sqlAdminGroupObjectId
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    }
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }  
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource sqlDB 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: sqlDBName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
    tier: 'Basic'
    capacity: 5
  }
  properties: {
    requestedBackupStorageRedundancy: 'Zone'
  }
}
```

With all this setup properly and deployed successfully, I still get this error in the logs of my container app:

`Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.`

I can't figure out what is missing in my config/setup for it to work. I would really like for this to work since not having to setup a password seems to be the best option to me. I tried multiple tweaks in my configs, bicep files and directly on the portal without success.

Comment: Did you assign the managed identity to the container app? Which version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` are you using? Can you confirm that networking is all good?

Comment: I have 5.1.1 installed. Networking seems good as my container app seems to be contacting the DB correctly. Problem seems to be coming from the DB itself not recognizing the user assigned managed identity.

`No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.`

In the database I have ran this script to create the user:

`CREATE USER [myUaiName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH OBJECT_ID='xxx'`

And assigned it the db_owner role but I still get this error.

Comment: did you assign the identity to the container app itselft ?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the Identity -> User assigned section of my CA

Comment: oh in the db connection string: `User ID=${identity.properties.principalId}`. this should be  `User ID=${identity.properties.clientId}`

Comment: see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-managed-identity-authentication

Comment: The container app returns the same error message with this change. There must be something else missing in my setup. Still investigating

Comment: have you tried running `CREATE USER [myUaiName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` without specifying the object_id ?

Comment: Yes! I had a feeling this might be an issue since it didn't seem to be necessary in the documentation so I dropped my user to recreate it without the OBJECT_ID and still no success

Comment: this error: `No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId` is it coming from azure identity library ? or sql ?

Comment: From Azure.Identity: 
`---> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.`

Comment: from within the container app ()using container app console) can you acquire a token for sql ?

Comment: I don't think so, this seems to be the issue actually. If i look at my stack trace, the error is thrown from there: `at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, Response response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` 
`at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Comment: can you try remove the ideneity from the container app and add it again ? maybe there was an issue assigning the managed identity

Comment: Done. I also tried re-creating my the user in my db that represents the UAI without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I had two problems with myh connection string:

1. I had to use the clientId instead of principalId of my UAI for the User Id,
2. `Encrypt=True` was missing from my connection string

My final ConnectionString looks like this: `Server=${databaseHost},1433;Database=${databaseName};Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User ID=${identity.properties.clientId}'; Encrypt=True`

I also updated all of my nuget packages to use their latest versions